# Open source equivalent to FiveRun' Tuneup

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there an open source equivalent to FiveRun's Tuneup product for Ruby on Rails performance measurments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's ruby-prof

http://ruby-prof.rubyforge.org/

It's a bit more technical in it's reports, but has been proven to be very valuable when hunting for performance issues.